# Rearranging open windows to monitors with shortcut / hotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, monitor

I often have multiple windows open on multiple monitors. I know that I can use WIN+SHIFT+Arrows to move them around. I use this feature very often.

Is there an easy way to press a shortcut/hotkey and already active windows are assigend/rearranged to defined monitors?

e.g. I press CTRL+SHIFT+X and my current open Outlook (on monito 3) moves fullscreen to monitor 1, my Visual Studio Code Windows moves to monitor 2 and Excel opens on monitor 3.
So via shortcut I always have the same "view". I new virtual desktops but they dont prevent me from arranging.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: The easiest way: use automation tool like AHK.  Another way - get [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1324007) from SU community.

Comment: Have you addition information regarding that tool "AHK" ?